How to make a responsive design 3 column with the first colum that becomes row
I'm trying to make a simple responsive CSS design with 3 columns.
When the screen resolution is less then "X" it has to add a line break and the first column (menu) has to became a row.
For now what I made it's (snippet with code inside):


* { box-sizing: border-box; }
html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
.A { background-color: #333333; }
.B { background-color: #777777; }
.C { background-color: #999999; }
    
:root {
    --A: 214px;
    --C: 214px;
    --B: calc(100vw - var(--A) - var(--C));
}

.flex-row {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.line_break_for_mobile {
    flex-basis: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: red;
}

.A {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    .line_break_for_mobile { display: none !important; }
    .A {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        width: var(--A);
        flex: 0 0 var(--A);
    }
    .C {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        width: var(--C);
        flex: 0 0 var(--C);
    }
    .B {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        width: var(--B);
    }
}
<div class="flex-row">
    <div class="A">
        <ul>
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    
    <div class="line_break_for_mobile"></div>

    <div class="B">
    Something
    </div>

    <div class="C">
        <ul>
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>



It works good for desktop screen, but I'm not very good with flex divs and the line break does not break so well (it has to take all the screen width).
It has to send div B and C to the next line.
What I'm trying to write it's that the layout should become like the one in this photo for small screen resolution:
Layout for mobile
So, how to do it?



   

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>Responsive Layout: Desktop Row, Mobile A on top</title>
      <style>
        * {
          box-sizing: border-box;
        }
    
        html,
        body {
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
          height: 100%;
        }
    
        .flex-container {
          display: flex;
          flex-wrap: wrap;
          height: 100%;
        }
    
        .A {
          background-color: #333333;
        }
    
        .B {
          background-color: #777777;
        }
    
        .C {
          background-color: #999999;
        }
    
        .A,
        .B,
        .C {
          display: flex;
          justify-content: center;
          align-items: center;
          color: yellow;
          font-size: 24px;
          font-weight: bold;
        }
    
        /* Mobile layout */
        @media only screen and (max-width: 599px) {
          .A {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100px;
            order: -1;
            /* this ensures A is always at the top */
          }
    
          .B,
          .C {
            width: 50%;
            height: calc(100% - 100px);
            /* this subtracting A's height */
          }
        }
    
        /* Desktop layout */
        @media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    
          .A,
          .B,
          .C {
            width: 33.33%;
            height: 100%;
          }
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    
    <body>
      <div class="flex-container">
        <div class="A">
          <ul>
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="B">Something</div>
        <div class="C">
          <ul>
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>
    
    </html>



Hope this help

Bugged for some screen resolutions. Try it. I think order: -1; for A it's not needed (A is anyway at top). No line break added. No fixed resolution at 214 for A and C. I think you're on the right track, but use the snippet as a starting point for next time. In any case it helped. However it works for both mobile and desktop screen resolution. I had skipped flex-wrap: wrap;. It's a topic I don't master and I should delve deeper into. Bye

This answer could be improved by adding some explanation.
